# MySQL Workbench and Unmet Dependencies. Solution?

Tags: apt, package-management, mysql, dependencies

I am trying to install MySQL Workbench through the System Settings and I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

    mysql-workbench: Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0) but 1:6.0.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libgdal.so.1-1.11.3 but it is a virtual package
                     Depends: libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 1:2.24.0) but 1:2.24.4-2 is to be installed
                     Depends: libpcrecpp0v5 (>= 7.7) but 2:8.38-3.1 is to be installed
                     Depends: python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~) but it is a virtual package
                     Depends: mysql-workbench-data (= 6.3.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1) but 6.3.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: I get the following error:

`Removing mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/my.cnf corrupt: invalid status
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: Now run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: `sudo dpkg --configure -a`


Ran well, no results/printouts.

Comment: Now try again to install Workbench!

Comment: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-workbench : Depends: libgdal.so.1-1.11.3
                   Depends: libgdal1i (>= 1.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`  

That's what I get when I try to install the workbench.

Comment: Do `sudo apt update`, then `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: I get error when updating:

`E: The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and got around it by downloading a .deb for mysql-workbench directly from the provider. Hopefully this helps someone else...

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/